# Debugging C++ project on Ubuntu in Eclipse won't stop at breakpoint

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

I'm running a C++ project on Ubuntu 12 in Eclipse.  I put a breakpoint in the main method.
I can see from the console window that the application is running.  But it doesn't stop at my breakpoint.  So, my question is...in Eclipse 3.7.2 why isn't it stopping at my breakpoint?
Are there settings I might be missing?  I have seen it stop 2 times but I click "Resume" and the application runs.  But then the next several times it doesn't stop at the breakpoint.  What am I missing?

Any ideas would be appreciated!

EV

Update:  I'm now seeing this in my Console window:

```
 Error in re-setting breakpoint 2: Warning:
 Cannot insert breakpoint 2.
 Error accessing memory address 0x8054ff2: Input/output error.

 Warning:
 Cannot insert breakpoint 2.
 Error accessing memory address 0x8054ff2: Input/output error.
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will show a checked purple circle as a break point that is active and just a purple circle as a break point that is set.  If yours aren't checkmarked there are several options for break points in the "breakpoints" view. Right click on the break point you have et and make sure the type is set to regular.

Comment: I am seeing both a check and a circle.

Comment: Right click on the break point you have set from the breakpoints view menu and make sure the type is set to regular.

Comment: Seems like this error can be caused by quite a few things. Can you past the code you are trying to debug? Or try to debug a simple hello world program created by eclipse from scratch just to make sure it works at all.